# 1-2 digit number, but not 0 (i.e. any number 1-99)

Tags: regex

I'm new to regular expressions.

I'm stuck how to modify [0..9]{1,2} (this matches any 1-2 digit number I think) to match any number 1 to 99

so, how could I match any number 1-99 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1 to 99, you can use `[1-9][0-9]?`,